# How to fix ‘No topic route info in name server for the topic’ exception in RocketmqClient

Tags: java, rocketmq

I'm using apache-rocketmq to send message,but got an exception.I tryed much solutions from csdn, but it does't work.Now i hava no idea how to do with it.

This is a Linux server, running rocketmq 4.2.0, java 8 and tomcat 8.

```
2019-05-06 15:16:01,440 WARN RocketmqClient(256) - doRebalance, eventConsumer, but the topic[alarm_event] not exist.
2019-05-06 15:16:09,230 INFO RocketmqRemoting(454) - createChannel: begin to connect remote host[122.114.164.162:24314] asynchronously
2019-05-06 15:16:09,232 INFO RocketmqRemoting(615) - NETTY CLIENT PIPELINE: CONNECT  UNKNOW => /122.114.164.162:24314
2019-05-06 15:16:12,232 WARN RocketmqRemoting(477) - createChannel: connect remote host[122.114.164.162:24314] timeout 3000ms, DefaultChannelPromise@59d7f51c(uncancellable)
2019-05-06 15:16:12,234 INFO RocketmqRemoting(640) - NETTY CLIENT PIPELINE: CLOSE 
2019-05-06 15:16:12,234 INFO RocketmqRemoting(286) - closeChannel: the channel[122.114.164.162:24314] was removed from channel table
2019-05-06 15:16:12,234 INFO RocketmqRemoting(640) - NETTY CLIENT PIPELINE: CLOSE 
2019-05-06 15:16:12,234 INFO RocketmqRemoting(280) - eventCloseChannel: the channel[null] has been removed from the channel table before
2019-05-06 15:16:12,235 INFO RocketmqRemoting(203) - closeChannel: close the connection to remote address[] result: true
2019-05-06 15:16:21,441 WARN RocketmqClient(256) - doRebalance, eventConsumer, but the topic[alarm_event] not exist.
2019-05-06 15:16:29,558 WARN RocketmqClient(1212) - get Topic [alarm_event] RouteInfoFromNameServer is not exist value
2019-05-06 15:16:29,558 WARN RocketmqClient(658) - updateTopicRouteInfoFromNameServer Exception
org.apache.rocketmq.client.exception.MQClientException: CODE: 17  DESC: No topic route info in name server for the topic: alarm_event
See http://rocketmq.apache.org/docs/faq/ for further details.
    at org.apache.rocketmq.client.impl.MQClientAPIImpl.getTopicRouteInfoFromNameServer(MQClientAPIImpl.java:1227)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.client.impl.MQClientAPIImpl.getTopicRouteInfoFromNameServer(MQClientAPIImpl.java:1197)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.client.impl.factory.MQClientInstance.updateTopicRouteInfoFromNameServer(MQClientInstance.java:605)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.client.impl.factory.MQClientInstance.updateTopicRouteInfoFromNameServer(MQClientInstance.java:492)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.client.impl.factory.MQClientInstance.updateTopicRouteInfoFromNameServer(MQClientInstance.java:361)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.client.impl.factory.MQClientInstance$3.run(MQClientInstance.java:278)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should run a rocketmq-console-ng application  to manage your topic,and then you can create a topic that you want to use in your program.
the address of rocketmq-console-ng:  https://github.com/apache/rocketmq-externals